# Search Through Columns With the Same Name (in the same dataset) and Create a New Column That Takes the Value the First Value Populated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have the following dataframe

```
| Number | Number  | Name | Name | Country | Country  |
| ------ | ------- | ---- | ---- | ------- | -------  |
| 1      | Nan     | Bob  | Nan  | USA     | Nan      |
| 4      | Nan     | Nan  | Nan  | India   | Nan      |
| Nan    | 12      | Joe  | Nan  | Nan     | China    |
| Nan    | 6       | Nan  | Matt | Nan     | Australia|
```

My question is, how do I create new Number, Name, Country columns (etc.) that just finds the like column and then sees which column is populated and pulls that value. Note in this example I only have two duplicate columns but would ideally like to be able to handle many different duplicate columns not just two.

So far I have the following code to identify the duplicate columns and then create a dictionary a key which is the desired column name and then the values are just the numbered original columns. (e.g. {'country': ['country_2', 'country_1']})

How can I now traverse through this dictionary and create a new "country" column that parses through all of the values in the list dictionary to find which column is populated?

Comment: `df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).first()`. But why would you have duplicate column names?

Comment: once you load the data in a ```pandas``` dataframe digits will be added automatically at the end of the column names, so when imported your columns will be something like: ```['Number', 'Number.1', 'Name', 'Name.1', 'Country', 'Country.1']```. So what you do is remove the digits, assign back the clean columns and use @Quang Hoang's code.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try with `stack`, `dropna` and `unstack`:

```
>>> df.stack().dropna().unstack()

     Country  Name Number
0        USA   Bob    1.0
1      India   NaN    4.0
2      China   Joe   12.0
3  Australia  Matt    6.0
```